# Linq Count from other model?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I will like to show number of module that belongs to segment and bind it to view.
In Linq below i was try to join segment table with site table and module table.
How can i show the count number of module that belongs to one segment?

My Linq:

```
var SiteSegmentModuleTable = (from site in db.Site.AsEnumerable()
                        join segment in db.Segment.AsEnumerable() on
                        site.SiteID equals segment.SiteID
                        join module in db.Module.AsEnumerable() on
                        segment.SegmentID equals module.SegmentID
                        group module by module.ModuleID into g // < causing error to segment and site binding
                         select new Segment()
                         {
                            ModuleCount = g.Count(), // will it work?
                            SegmentID = segment.SegmentID,
                            SiteName = site.SiteName,
                            SegmentName = segment.SegmentName,
                            CreatedBy = segment.CreatedBy,
                            ModifiedBy = segment.ModifiedBy,
                            CreatedOn = segment.CreatedOn,
                            LastModifiedOn = segment.LastModifiedOn
                           }).ToList();
```

Any guidance and suggestion is highly appreciate!
Thanks alot!

Comment: What is the specific error that you are getting?  Also why are you using `AsEnumerable`?  That will cause this code to make 3 calls to the DB to get all the data in the Site, Segment and Module tables.  Finally you really should take advantage of navigation properties instead of doing joins.

Comment: hi @juharr im using AsEnumerable because i want to bind the site.SiteName from another model into Segment View. I trying to find a better solution too. What do you mean by navigation properties?

Comment: Typically when you create a context in EF (or Linq to SQL) if you DB is set up with foreign keys between associated tables then it will create navigation properties so you could do something like `from site in db.Site from segment in site.Segments select segment.Modules.Count()`.  But I still don't understand why you're using `AsEnumerable`.  Have you tried it without it?

Comment: Hi @juharr,yes i tried without the AsEnumerable but the linq shows error:
"The entity or complex type 'MyProjectl.Models.UserRole' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query. "

I had googled it and it need use AsEnumerable because i need to show other data from other model to current view. Thanks for your info anyway!

Comment: You should only have one `AsEnumerable` then.  Just select into an anonymous class like `select new { segment, site.SiteName, a.Count() }` then take the result and do a `.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Segment() { ModuleCount = x.Count, SegmentID = x.segment.SegmentID, SiteName = x.SiteName, .... );`

Comment: I see! Nice info! I tried it and works! Thanks alot for your prompt feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is my temporary workaround which able to show the module count number into my mvc view. Hope it can be improved in future..

Linq:

```
var SiteSegmentTable = (from module in db.Module.AsEnumerable()
                                    group module by module.SegmentID into a
                                    join segment in db.Segment.AsEnumerable() on a.FirstOrDefault().SegmentID equals segment.SegmentID
                                    join site in db.Site.AsEnumerable() on segment.SiteID equals site.SiteID
                                    select new Segment()
                                    {
                                        ModuleCount =  a.Count(),
                                        SegmentID = segment.SegmentID,
                                        SiteName = site.SiteName,
                                        SegmentName = segment.SegmentName,
                                        CreatedBy = segment.CreatedBy,
                                        ModifiedBy = segment.ModifiedBy,
                                        CreatedOn = segment.CreatedOn,
                                        LastModifiedOn = segment.LastModifiedOn
                                    }).ToList();
```